# Storing multiple choice answers of a survey in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-design, survey

I try to create a survey app using asp.net (c#) based on ms sql server. The user can see multiple choice, single choice, and textbox answer choices to input. I am able to store textbox and single choice answers in my database but I am stuck on storing multiple answers.

My design is the following:

**employee** : (id, username)

**survey_title** : (id, title, description, creation_data)

**survey_answer_type** : (id, type_name)

**survey_question** : (id, question, survey_id, survey_answer_type_id)

**survey_answer** : (id, question_id, answer) -*all answer choices (answer is null if answer type is textbox)*-

**survey_eanswer** : (id, employee_id, answer_id, str_answer) *-answers of employees (str_answer is used to store textbox answers)-*

I could not find a way to store multiple answers in my survey_eanswer table, and I know that comma separated inputs are not a good design strategy.

Thanks.

Comment: You might find some advantage if you turn it around, and think about what form you want to be able to get data *out* in - for example, if you need to query "people who ticked answer 'c' for question 4", you might find that multiple rows in `survey_eanswer` for each question is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good design would be to have a table

**survey_question_options**: (ID,QUESTION_ID,OPTION)

|ID|question_id|option|
|1|1|red|
|2|1|blue|
|3|1|white|
|4|2|small|
|5|2|medium|
|6|2|large|

And then just save the id of the choosen option. 
Save each choosen option as own separate db entry.
This enables you to use the standard sql operations to join/group and evalute your survey at the end.

Example, you want to now how many users have choosen medium:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM survey_answers
WHERE question_ID = 2 AND answer = 2
```

Or, more complex but meaning the same:

```
SELECT Count(survey_answer.id)
FROM survey_answers
LEFT JOIN survey_question_options ON
    survey_question_options.ID = survey_answers.Answer AND
    survey_question_options.question_ID = survey_answers.question
WHERE survey_answer.question_ID = 2 
    AND survey_question_options.option LIKE 'medium'
```

Comment: My survey_answer table exactly does the same thing. But what happens if, for example, you chose both small and medium for the question 2. How can I store the ids 4 and 5 in survey_eanswer in a sensible way?

Comment: Ah, you have a question that allows multiple answers... I see. In that case, I would just a new entry for every answer. If the person choose option 1,3 - add one db entry of option 1 and an other for option 3.

Comment: Thank you, my thought was complex yet the solution is simple :)